# How do I create a fixed Flexbox header?

Tags: html, css

I can't get the the header to stay fixed without the black universal background disappearing. Whenever I add the the position property with the "fixed" value, the background black color apparently becomes transparent.

```css
.nav-container {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid seashell;
  height: 69px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="nav-container">
    <a href="#"> <img src="./resources/img-tea-cozy-logo.png" /></a>
    <ul class="navigation">
      <li><a href="#">Mission</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Featured Tea</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Locations</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: There is no black background-color in the code you posted.

Comment: The black background-colour is a universal declaration, for the entire page. I tried specifying it for the header but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Make the container of the flex div to be position fixed. Also set the width to 100%

```css
.nav-container {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid seashell;
  height: 69px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="nav-container">
      <a href="#"> <img src="./resources/img-tea-cozy-logo.png" /></a>
      <ul class="navigation">
        <li><a href="#">Mission</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Featured Tea</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Locations</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div style="height: 30000px; padding-top:69px;">scroll</div>


  <body>
```

Comment: this will cause a collision at the start as the element is already moved out of the flow at the start. Easier to use `position: sticky` instead.

Comment: what is it suppose to do? `position: sticky` doesn't seem to do anything, it just scrolls with the page

Comment: it does you just have to declare `top: 0` to it as unlike `position: fixed` your browser will not correct the missing property: https://codepen.io/tacoshy/pen/dymjemb

Comment: Thanks so much guys. The  "sticky" value seems to work. Thanks again.